# Is there any time or situation when a father revokes a minor son's vows?

Tags: halacha, nedarim-shevuot, minor-katan-child

The parsha Matot talks of a father revoking his young daughter's vows.  This seems to refer to the time period when the daughter is between 11 and 12 years of age:
https://dafyomi.co.il/nazir/backgrnd/nz-in-019.htm

Is there any time or situation when a father can or should revoke a son's vows?

Comment: In a case where heter nedarim wouldn’t apply?

Comment: The Gemara explains the reason for hafara is because the girl/wife have automatic subconscious kavannah that it should only be in force if their father/husband agrees to it. A don has no such kavvanah.

Comment: if we are talking about the method of הפרח then as per N.T. there is no such provision. The question left is can a father use the method of התרה either as member of a Beis Din or יחיד מומחה

Answer (score 0):

The father has no such ability in regards to his son.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you supported this point with sources